# Nginx init.d script

Tags: debian, nginx, init.d

After a dist-upgrade on my debian machine yesterday I am having some problems with the nginx init script. Whenever I try to start nginx using the init script it comes up with a error message:

```
# service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Output of systemctl status nginx.service:

```
# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-05-19 12:36:12 CEST; 7s ago
  Process: 14087 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14126 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Output of journalctl -xn:

```
# journalctl -xn
systemd[1]: nginx.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
systemd[14126]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/sbin/nginx could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The process /usr/sbin/nginx could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned while executing this process is 2.
systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

my nginx file in init.d:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nginx
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -f /etc/default/nginx ] ; then
    . /etc/default/nginx
fi

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS || true
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid \
        --exec $DAEMON || true
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \
        /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON || true
    sleep 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \
        /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS || true
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
  reload)
      echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
      start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid \
          --exec $DAEMON || true
      echo "$NAME."
      ;;
  status)
      status_of_proc -p /usr/local/nginx/logs/$NAME.pid "$DAEMON" nginx && exit 0 || exit $?
      ;;
  *)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The nginx daemon file is located in `/usr/local/sbin/nginx` (I compiled it there).

Things i've tried so far:
I copied the daemon file `/usr/local/sbin/nginx` to `/usr/sbin/nginx`

When I use `service nginx start` it hangs on starting nginx. When I try to connect to port 80 it does work. So I proceeded to edit my init script and change `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` to `PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. This however gave the same result.

I haven't triedd anything else so far.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have another debian machine with the same version of debian (recently newly installed) which runs very well on the said init.d script.

Comment: @SanderKoenders did you check if the pid file aready exists? Also on what port is nginx listening?  Are you using nginx with php-fpm?  what does  `lsof -i :[nginxportnr]`  tell you.  See also  `netstat -tanulp`  what it reports. You could try to run `nginx` with `strace`

Comment: Thanks guys, thanks to the point Christopher made I was able to solve the problem. The answer below with my comment explains how I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my nginx file in init.d:

… is *entirely irrelevant*.   Look at the output of `systemctl`.  It told you exactly what file to look at:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
```

*That* is your service unit.  And `systemctl` is telling you what that service unit has configured for preparing to start the service:

```
 Process: 14126 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

That's what you'll find in the `ExecStartPre` setting in the service unit. You'll notice from it that `PATH` is also entirely irrelevant (which is by design in systemd).  The journal was even more explicit about what happened:

```
systemd[14126]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory
```

Whatever you may think, the computer thinks that at the time that you tried to start that service `/usr/sbin/nginx` could not be run as a program because no file existed by that name.

My educated guess is that you have a `RootDirectory` setting in your service unit, and either you copied the file to the `/usr/sbin` that is *not* within the changed root environment or some ancillary shared libraries necessary for loading the program image are missing from the changed root environment.

Comment: You're right actually, I was going to post the solution I found to the problem, which is a `/etc/system/systemd/nginx` file I got from a fedora site. When this file was configured properly I could trow away the `/etc/init.d/nginx` file entirely and use the new service file with `systemctl enable /etc/system/systemd/nginx.service`. I wasn't aware of the switch debian made with their init scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in debian 8. For me I find

```
[date] debian systemd[1]: nginx.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
```

at /var/log/syslog, which is similar as the question

```
# journalctl -xn
systemd[1]: nginx.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
```

The reason is that in /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service I have

```
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
```

But since the nginx is build it writes pid at /usr/local/nginx/log/nginx.pid

The fix is to change/add the line at /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
```